# how to update array in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to update values from an array. 
i can create but if I try to update, it updates only last value. 
if I use save() i get an error. I tried everything i could researching. no success.
here is my code.

```
$products = $request->all();

      $name = $products['name'];
      $price = $products['price'];
      $qty = $products['qty'];
      $total = $products['total'];

    foreach( $name as $key => $n) {

        $invoice->products()->update([ 

            'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
            'name' => $name[$key],
            'price' => $price[$key],
            'qty' => $qty[$key],
            'total' => $total[$key]
        ]);



     }
```

if I use save() i get this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given,
```

thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to do or achieve ? Also, the code provided seems to be incomplete and unclear. Please show some more code.

Comment: There is a problem in the logic here `$name` is just a string ! or not ? and as the error said `... save() must be an instance of Model array given` so you should pass a model to save() not an array !!

Comment: its clear to what i am trying to achieve.  Maraboc, tried to pass a mode to save and didn't work. I know the logic is wrong, just don't know how to fix as I am new in laravel. thanks

Comment: I can create with this same logic but I cannot update. thanks

Comment: what is `$invoice` here?

Comment: Updating invoice which has many products fields which i am struggling to save more than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $products = $request->all();


      $name = $products['name'];
      $price = $products['price'];
      $qty = $products['qty'];
      $total = $products['total'];

     foreach( $name as $key => $n) {

        $invoice->products()->create([ 

            'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
            'name' => $name[$key],
            'price' => $price[$key],
            'qty' => $qty[$key],
            'total' => $total[$key]
        ]);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help Mr. pyramid. here is the code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);

    $invoice->invoice_no = $request->invoice_no;
    $invoice->client = $request->client;
    $invoice->title = $request->title;
    $invoice->client_address = $request->client_address;
    $invoice->invoice_date = $request->invoice_date;
    $invoice->due_date = $request->due_date;
    $invoice->subtotal = $request->subtotal;
    $invoice->grandtotal = $request->grandtotal;

    $invoice->save();

    $products = $request->all();


      $name = $products['name'];
      $price = $products['price'];
      $qty = $products['qty'];
      $total = $products['total'];

     foreach( $name as $key => $n) {

        $invoice->products()->update([ 

             //=> $invoice->id,
            'name' => $name[$key],
            'price' => $price[$key],
            'qty' => $qty[$key],
            'total' => $total[$key]
        ]);
     } 




    Session::flash('success', 'Invoice Updated');

    return redirect()->route('invoices');

}
```

with this exactly code I can create and works fine but if i use to update it won't allow me.

database

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('invoice_no');
        $table->date('invoice_date');
        $table->date('due_date');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('client');
        $table->string('client_address');
        $table->decimal('subtotal');
        $table->decimal('grandtotal');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

products

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('invoice_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('qty');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->string('total');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

relationship

```
class Invoice extends Model {
protected $fillable =['client','client_address','title','invoice_no','invoice_date','due_date','discount', 'subtotal','grandtotal'];



public function products(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'invoice_id');
}
```

}

```
class Product extends Model
{

protected $casts = [
    'name' => 'array',
    'price' => 'array',
    'qty' => 'array',
    'total' => 'array'
];
protected $fillable = ['invoice_id','price','qty','total','name'];


public function invoice(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');

}
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I still have some doubts but I found something which I think can help you.

```
$invoice->products()->update($request->all());
```

Comment: ok please add few more code so that I can understand the flow. :) i am confused for `$invoice`